# Get all the table items from DynamoDB table using Java High Level API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I implemented scan operation using in dynamodb table using dynamodbmapper, but I'm not getting all the results. Scan returns different number of items, whenever I run my program.

Code snippet :

```
DyanmoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
List<Books> scanResult = mapper.scan(Books.class, scanExpression);
```

I investigated into it, and found out about the limit of the items scan returns. But I couln't find a way to get all the items from the table using mapper! Is there a way so I can loop through all the items of the table. I have set enough heap memory in JVM so there won't be memory issues.

Answer (score 8):

**In java use the DynamoDBScanExpression without any filter,**

```
// Change to your Table_Name (you can load dynamically from lambda env as well)
DynamoDBMapperConfig mapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().withTableNameOverride(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement("Table_Name")).build();

DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client, mapperConfig);

DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

// Change to your model class   
List < ParticipantReport > scanResult = mapper.scan(ParticipantReport.class, scanExpression);



// Check the count and iterate the list and perform as desired.
scanResult.size();
```

Comment: I just tried this code and not working.

Comment: kindly share the stacktrace or the error details

Comment: small correction it returns PaginatedScanList not List

Comment: This will only return the items up till DynamoDB's limit which is 1MB, you need to implement pagination in order to retrieve all the items. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html

Answer (score 4):

the scan should return all the items.
the catch is that the collection returned is **lazily loaded**. 
 you need to iterate through the List and when it consumes all the items that are fetched additional calls will be made behind the scenes to bring in more items (until everything is brought in).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaQueryScanORMModelExample.html

In that example it's:

```
List<Book> scanResult = mapper.scan(Book.class, scanExpression);

for (Book book : scanResult) {
    System.out.println(book);
}
```

Comment: Can you programmatically tell me how to implement that or give reference docs for it? Thanks

Comment: updated answer. there is no magic to it. you just interate over the list like you would with any list.

Comment: This is what I was doing earlier also. But I'm not getting all the items. Every time I run, I get different number of items.

Comment: how is the number different? is it increasing? is there a large variation? do you see additional calls to dynamo while you iterate through the list?

Comment: Not always increasing, they are just different everytime. And how do I check additional calls to dynamodb? I don't have much experience with dynamodb, I just started implementing it.

Comment: is the table by change changing? i would look at the network traffic with tcpdump to see if there are additional calls

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate until LastEvaluatedKey is no longer returned. Check how is done in one of the official examples from the SDK:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/23837f36944f4166c56988452475edee99868166/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/codesamples/lowlevel/LowLevelQuery.java#L70

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;

public final class LogFetcher {

    static AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    static String tableName = "SystemLog";

    public static List<SystemLog> findLogsForDeviceWithMacID(String macID) {

        client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(macID));

        DynamoDBQueryExpression<SystemLog> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<SystemLog>()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("parentKey = :val1")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

         List<SystemLog> requestedLogs = mapper.query(SystemLog.class, queryExpression);

        return requestedLogs;
    }
}
```

And sample class

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBRangeKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName="SystemLog")
public final class SystemLog {
    public Integer pidValue;
    public String uniqueId;
    public String parentKey;

    //DynamoDB

    //Partition (hash) key
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="parentKey")
    public String getParentKey() { return parentKey; }
    public void setParentKey(String parentKey) { this.parentKey = parentKey; }

    //Range key
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="uniqueId")
    public String getUniqueId() { return uniqueId; }
    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) { this.uniqueId = uniqueId;} 

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="pidValue")
    public Integer getPidValue() { return pidValue; }    
    public void setPidValue(Integer pidValue) { this.pidValue = pidValue; }
}
```

Comment: This is query expression which is different than a scan

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the **`DynamoDBMapper#scan`** method returns a **"lazy-loaded"** collection. It
>   initially returns only one page of results, and then makes a service
>   call for the next page if needed. To obtain all the matching items,
>   iterate over the paginated results collection.

However, PaginatedScanList comes with out of box **`PaginatedScanList#loadAllResults`** method which helps to eagerly load all results for this list.

**NOTE:** **`loadAllResults`** method is not supported in **ITERATION_ONLY** mode.

```
List<Books> scanResult = mapper.scan(Books.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
scanResult.loadAllResults();//Eagerly loads all results for this list.
//Total results loaded into the list
System.out.println(scanResult.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

`DyanmoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();`
`List<Books> scanResult = new ArrayList<Books>(mapper.scan(Books.class, scanExpression));`

This will work, it will iterate all the items and then returns a list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).